# What are some popular names of Vishnu which are also the names of Shiva in the Shiva Sahasranama?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, identification-request, name

In the Vishnu Sahasranama (thousand names of Vishnu), the names "Shiva" and "Rudra" are mentioned which Smarthas believe to be indicating nondifference between Vishnu and Shiva. Are there any popular names of Vishnu that are mentioned as Shiva's names in the Shiva Sahasranama (thousand names of Shiva) that can be used similarly to indicate nondifference between Vishnu and Shiva?

Comment: @KarmanyaNanda and LakshmiNarayan. I hope you know that there are chat rooms to discuss. Comment section is getting full. Please use [chat].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have found a total of 23 names:

- sthāṇu/sthāṇave (स्थाणु/स्थाणवे)
- Aniruddha (अनिरुद्ध)
- Bhāvaḥ (भावः)
- Prabhavaḥ (प्रभवः)
- Siddhaḥ (सिद्ध:)
- Sarveśvaraḥ (सर्वेश्वरः)
- Prajāpatiḥ (प्रजापतिः)
- Īśānaḥ (ईशानः)
- Vibhuḥ (विभु:)
- Sarvaḥ (सर्व:)
- Vyāsa (व्यास)
- Hari (हरि)
- Dhanurveda (धनुर्वेद)
- Yogī (योगी)
- Aparājita (अपराजित)
- Padmanābha (पद्मनाभ)
- Anila (अनिल)
- Vṛkṣa (वृक्ष)
- Dhruva (ध्रुव)
- Bhagvān (भगवान्)
- Prabhuḥ (प्रभुः)
- Sākṣī (साक्षी)
- Dakṣa (दक्ष)